# How to call Appdelegate function in PCL class using xamarin forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, appdelegate, portable-class-library

In my Xamarin Studio for MAC I use "Xamarin.Forms" solution. I want to use AppDelegate function in my PCL class. but I don't understand how to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in pcl. 
There is 2 variants how to do this.

Make abstraction lvl, in pcl create interface and in ios project implenent it.

And second variants is to use MessageCenter.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitry Zinoviev